# Error:(47) Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in android phone gap

Tags: android, xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am working in android studio.Here i am doing the toast popup message in android phone gap,but i am

getting Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in line no 47 in(xmlns:android     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets")

Below is config.xml code

Please suggest me.

Thank you in advance.

```
<widget
    xmlns:android     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0"> <!-- it represents major.minor.patch version system. -->
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>    
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>  <!-- This is a brief description of what the app is about, and what it is. -->

    <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>
   <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />

    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" version="1.0" />
    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <!-- for Android -->
    <feature name="Toast">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Toast" />
    </feature>
    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
    <plugins>
    </plugins>

</widget>
```

Comment: remove unwanted space

Answer (score 1):

Add this line  xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0".

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<widget
    xmlns:android     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0"> <!-- it represents major.minor.patch version system. -->
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>   

    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>  <!-- This is a brief description of what the app is about, and what it is. -->

    <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />

    <gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.toast" version="1.0" />
    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <!-- for Android -->
    <feature name="Toast">
        <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Toast" />
    </feature>
    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
    <plugins>
    </plugins>

</widget>
```